# Reading YUV data with Unity and Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I am trying to read YUV data from the Tango camera in order to do some image analysis processing that unfortunately cannot be done using shaders. I manage to render the image but not to read the raw data from the texture. When I attempt to read, for instance, the _Ytex texture, containing a packed Y channel I only get a series of bytes all equal to 205.

I have tried to intercept the texture from many points:

- `_OnExperimentalUnityFrameAvailable` in `VideoOverlayListener`
- `TangoARScreen`'s `Update` method
- `OnPostRender` method of the Camera object
- A few less relevant places.

On all I tried to access it both through `m_tangoApplication.GetVideoOverlayTextureYUV().m_videoOverlayTextureY` and through `m_screenMaterial.GetTexture("_YTex")` but always get a series of 205 values.

I am suspecting that the Tango SDK directly write the YUV values in the GPU memory but I am confused as to why a `GetTexture("_YTex")` fails to recover it.

I will probably end up making a specific render target for the sole purpose of extracting this data but surely there may be a more direct way to access the video streams?

Has anyone managed to do this? I am using the latest SDK version (Ancha)

Comment: Same is with my case, I had same experience as you